# Saving Object with path in Spring MVC

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I yould like to know if it is possible to directly save an object in a hibernate/spring/maven project with path. So my class has an object attribute "Category". In the form I have a select. If I put different Category objects as Value in select and I link the select with form:select and path to the Category attribute, will it save it automatically ? Otherwise I would have to get the ID, get back the object from the ID in my controller and then set the Category attribute with the setter in order to save the whole thing.

Thanks

Comment: are u asking for drop down box in Spring?

Comment: and u need to use from:select then it will automatically will take that path name according to the data.

Comment: Yeah I know this works for Strings and ints, ... But does it also work with objects ? Like a path="user" and user is an object

Comment: it can work if u can make object into the bean class :)